# How to calculate Gamma functions values for Quaternions using Mathematica?

Tags: special-functions, quaternions

How can we calculate the values for the **Gamma** function using **Quaternions** on Mathematica?

For example:

```
<<Quaternions`; (* load package *)

Gamma[5] = 24

N[Gamma[I]] = -0.15495 - 0.498016 I

N[Gamma[1 + 2 I]] = 0.151904 + 0.0198049 I

N[Gamma[Quaternion[5, 0, 0, 0]]] = Gamma[Quaternion[5., 0., 0., 0.]] (* which is wrong *)
```

Specially, how can we calculate

```
Gamma[Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 4]]?
```

Attempts:

```
N[Gamma[FromQuaternion[Quaternion[1, 2, 0, 0]]]] (* works *)
N[Gamma[FromQuaternion[Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 4]]]] (* doesn't work *)


QuaternionPower[x_, y_] := E^(y ** Log[x])
QuaternionGamma[z_] :=
          Integrate[QuaternionPower[E, -x + Log[x]*(z - 1)], {x, 0, Infinity}]
N[QuaternionGamma[FromQuaternion[Quaternion[1, 2, 0, 0]]]] =
  0.151904 + 0.0198049 I (* works *)
N[QuaternionGamma[FromQuaternion[Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 0]]]] =
  ConditionalExpression[Gamma[(1.  + 2. I) + 3. J], Re[J] > -0.333333] (* doesn't work *)
```

Comment: It works for me in 12.1. What version are you using?

Comment: o.O, I'm using 12.1 as well, what is the result that you've found?

Comment: Ugh, it returns `Gamma[(1. + 2. I) + 3. J + 4. K]` for me and I thought it's some special form.

Comment: Hum, I see. Unforunately it is not really the case, `(1. + 2. I) + 3. J + 4. K` is just the open form of `N[Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 4]]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the function to be applied to a quaternion is *holomorphic/meromorphic*, one way to proceed is to switch to the complex matrix representation of a quaternion (see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations)), and then apply `MatrixFunction[]` to it.

For instance,

```
<< Quaternions`

BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; (* for reproducibility *)
            qq = Quaternion @@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 4]]
   Quaternion[-1.01205, 0.826338, -1.39379, 0.41692]

Tan[qq] (* elementary example *)
   Quaternion[-0.0652529, 0.50833, -0.857402, 0.256472]

Quaternion @@ Flatten[ReIm[First[MatrixFunction[Tan,
                                        {{qq[[1]] + I qq[[2]], qq[[3]] + I qq[[4]]},
                                         {-qq[[3]] + I qq[[4]], qq[[1]] - I qq[[2]]}}]]]]
   Quaternion[-0.0652529, 0.50833, -0.857402, 0.256472]
```

Thus, to evaluate a gamma function for quaternion argument:

```
Quaternion @@ Flatten[ReIm[First[MatrixFunction[Gamma,
                                        {{qq[[1]] + I qq[[2]], qq[[3]] + I qq[[4]]},
                                         {-qq[[3]] + I qq[[4]], qq[[1]] - I qq[[2]]}}]]]]
   Quaternion[-0.0568728, 0.0210734, -0.0355446, 0.0106324]
```

---

Now, for a warning. The reason I emphasized the requirement of analyticity is that if the function has branch cuts, then the complex matrix method might give results that are the conjugate of the expected result, due to possible differences in branch cut choice. For instance,

```
Log[qq] (* a consistent example *)
   Quaternion[0.670588, 1.04449, -1.76174, 0.526985]

Quaternion @@ Flatten[ReIm[First[MatrixFunction[Log,
                                        {{qq[[1]] + I qq[[2]], qq[[3]] + I qq[[4]]},
                                         {-qq[[3]] + I qq[[4]], qq[[1]] - I qq[[2]]}}]]]]
   Quaternion[0.670588, 1.04449, -1.76174, 0.526985]

q2 = Reverse[qq] (* inconsistent example *)

Log[q2]
   Quaternion[0.670588, 0.989246, -0.586497, 0.718306]

(* note that this returns the conjugate *)
Quaternion @@ Flatten[ReIm[First[MatrixFunction[Log,
                                        {{q2[[1]] + I q2[[2]], q2[[3]] + I q2[[4]]},
                                         {-q2[[3]] + I q2[[4]], q2[[1]] - I q2[[2]]}}]]]]
   Quaternion[0.670588, -0.989246, 0.586497, -0.718306]
```

Comment: Very interesting approach, thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 3):

I have decided to write another answer, because the following is more specific to the case of the gamma function. In particular, I will demonstrate how to modify the OP's original approach.

The reason the OP's method failed is that the elementary functions in *Mathematica* are left unevaluated for symbolic quaternion arguments. For instance,

```
<<Quaternions`

Exp[Quaternion[a, b, c, d]]
   E^Quaternion[a, b, c, d]
```

To make the OP's proposal work, one will need to manually split the quaternion into its scalar and vector parts. Using e.g. the formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Exponential,_logarithm,_and_power_functions), we can write the following:

```
ig[Quaternion[a_, b_, c_, d_], x_] := 
   With[{l = Log[x], vs = Sqrt[{b, c, d}.{b, c, d}]},
        (x^(a - 1) Exp[-x]) Prepend[l {b, c, d} Sinc[l vs], Cos[l vs]]]
```

Then, we can do this:

```
qq = Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 0];

Quaternion @@ Integrate[ig[qq, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
   Quaternion[1/2 (Gamma[1 - I Sqrt[13]] + Gamma[1 + I Sqrt[13]]),
              (I (Gamma[1 - I Sqrt[13]] - Gamma[1 + I Sqrt[13]]))/Sqrt[13],
              (3 I (Gamma[1 - I Sqrt[13]] - Gamma[1 + I Sqrt[13]]))/(2 Sqrt[13]), 0]

N[%] // Chop
   Quaternion[-0.003441450173902947, 0.008960473460683197, 0.013440710191024793, 0]
```

Compare with the matrix function approach:

```
Quaternion @@ Flatten[ReIm[First[MatrixFunction[Gamma,
                        {{qq[[1]] + I qq[[2]], qq[[3]] + I qq[[4]]},
                         {-qq[[3]] + I qq[[4]], qq[[1]] - I qq[[2]]}}]]]] // FullSimplify
   Quaternion[1/2 (Gamma[1 - I Sqrt[13]] + Gamma[1 + I Sqrt[13]]),
              (I (Gamma[1 - I Sqrt[13]] - Gamma[1 + I Sqrt[13]]))/Sqrt[13],
              (3 I (Gamma[1 - I Sqrt[13]] - Gamma[1 + I Sqrt[13]]))/(2 Sqrt[13]), 0]
```

and we see the two methods give consistent results.

Comment: The approach with the matrices I've found exciting, since I can adapt the calculation to work with reals, complexes or quaternions.

Answer (score 2):

With my [GeometricAlgebra paclet](https://github.com/sw1sh/GeometricAlgebra) you can work with any geometric number and apply any `MatrixFunction` supported function on them with `MultivectorFunction` , that effectively just converts numbers to matrices and back. Quaternions can be simply expressed as `GeometricAlgebra[0,2]`:

```
PacletInstall["https://wolfr.am/OkONsyY2"]

<< GeometricAlgebra`

MultivectorFunction[Gamma, 
  Multivector[{a, b, c, d}, {0, 2}]] // Simplify
```

Convert quaternion to matrix:

```
MultivectorMatrix[Multivector[{a, b, c, d}, {0, 2}]]["Numeric"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code (with help of other community members) for working with quaternions:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[x_?NumberQ, y_] := x y;
Protect[Dot];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_?MatrixQ] := 
  First[First[x]] /; x == First[First[x]] IdentityMatrix[Length[x]];
Matrix /: NonCommutativeMultiply[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], y_] := 
  Dot[Matrix[x], y];
Matrix /: NonCommutativeMultiply[y_, Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := 
  Dot[y, Matrix[x]];
Matrix /: Dot[Matrix[x_], Matrix[y_]] := Matrix[x . y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_] + Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ + Matrix[y_] := 
  Matrix[x IdentityMatrix[Length[y]] + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_]*Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x . y] /; x . y == y . x;
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], y_?NumericQ] := 
  Matrix[MatrixPower[x, y]];
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], Matrix[y_?MatrixQ]] := 
  Exp[Matrix[y] . Log[Matrix[x]]];
Matrix /: Im[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Im[x]]
Matrix /: Re[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Re[x]]
Matrix /: Arg[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Arg[x]]

$Post2 = FullSimplify[FullSimplify[# /. i -> Matrix[( {
               {I, 0},
               {0, -I}
              } )] /. j -> Matrix[( {
              {0, 1},
              {-1, 0}
             } )] /. k -> Matrix[( {
             {0, I},
             {I, 0}
            } ) ] /. 
        f_[args1___?NumericQ, Matrix[mat_], args2___?NumericQ] :> 
         Matrix[MatrixFunction[f[args1, #, args2] &, mat]]] /. 
      Matrix[{{a_, c_}, {d_, b_}}] :> 
       Re[a] + Im[a] i + Re[c] j + Im[c] k ] /. 
    Matrix[{{a_, c_}, {d_, b_}}] :> 
     Re[a] + Im[a] i + Re[c] j + Im[c] k &;
$Post = Nest[$Post2, #, 3] &;
```

After running it, you can use quaternionic $i$,$j$,$k$ inside any expressions alongside other numbers. The multiplication is evaluated only if the quaternions commute. For non-commutative multiplication one can use non-commutative multiplication operator (`x ** y`), it is evaluated always.

Test it:

```
In=Re[(j + k)^a]

Out=2^(a/2) Cos[(a Pi)/2]

In=Log[j+k]

Out=1/4 (Sqrt[2] (j+k) Pi+Log[4])

In=Sin[j + k]

Out=((j+k) Sinh[Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[2]

In=Sqrt[j+k]

Out=(Sqrt[2]+j+k)/2^(3/4)

In=Log[j + k] ** Log[i + k]

Out=1/8 ((-1+i+j-k) Pi^2+Sqrt[2] (i+j+2 k) Pi Log[2]+2 Log[2]^2)

In=Sign[j + k]

Out=(j+k)/Sqrt[2]

In=1/(i + k)

Out=1/2 (-i-k)
```

P.S. Your specific example gives answer

```
In:= Gamma[1+2i+3j+4k]

Out:= ((Sqrt[29] + 2 I i + 3 I j + 4 I k) Gamma[
       1 - I Sqrt[29]] + (Sqrt[29] - 2 I i - 3 I j - 4 I k) Gamma[
       1 + I Sqrt[29]])/(2 Sqrt[29])
```

The `I` here is non-quaternionic and cancels out in numeric computation:

```
In:= % //N

Out:= -0.000318107 - 0.000442456 i - 0.000663684 j - 0.000884911 k
```

The general formula for Gamma function is thus

```
In:= NumericQ[a] = NumericQ[b] = NumericQ[c] = NumericQ[d] = True; 

In:= Gamma[a + b i + c j + d k]

Out:= k Im[-(((c + I d) (Gamma[a - Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2]] - 
       Gamma[a + Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2]]))/(
    2 Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2]))] + 
 i Im[((-I b + Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2]) Gamma[
      a - Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2]] + (I b + 
       Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2]) Gamma[a + Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2]])/(
   2 Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2])] + 
 j Re[-(((c + I d) (Gamma[a - Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2]] - 
       Gamma[a + Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2]]))/(
    2 Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2]))] + 
 Re[((-I b + Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2]) Gamma[
     a - Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2]] + (I b + 
      Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2]) Gamma[a + Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2]])/(
  2 Sqrt[-b^2 - c^2 - d^2])]
```

Comment: @GarouDan I have updated my answer to inlude your example and a general formula for `Gamma` function.